# Resource must be in ARN format or "*"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

The following CloudFormation is validated and contains a SESAccessPolicy where some Parameters are passed.

Different Account IDs (for production : XXXXXXXXXXXXX and test: YYYYYYYYYYYYY)

```
Parameters:

  ProdEmailFromAddress:
    Type: String
    Description: "Email address to use as sender"
    Default: "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:identity/no-reply@company.no"

  TestEmailFromAddress:
    Type: String
    Description: "Email address to use as sender"
    Default: "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:YYYYYYYYYYYYY:identity/no-reply@companytest.no"

Conditions:
  IsProductionDeployment: !Equals [!Ref "AWS::AccountId", "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"]


SESAccessPolicy:
  Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      Description: Permissions to send email from SES
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - "ses:SendEmail"
            Resource:
              - !If [IsProductionDeployment,!Ref ProdEmailFromAddress, !Ref TestEmailFromAddress]
```

When updating the Stack we get the following Error Event

```
Resource no-reply@companytest.no must be in ARN format or "*". (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MalformedPolicyDocument; Request ID: 7af958ba-9c99-4073-a3b3-4da1b3ae80da; Proxy: null)
```

Although if i change the Resource at SESAccessPolicy from using a !Ref to a hardcoded String, it works and the stack is deployed.

```
Resource:
     - !If [IsProductionDeployment,!Ref ProdEmailFromAddress, "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:YYYYYYYYYYYYY:identity/no-reply@companytest.no" ]
```

I want to use the **!Ref** and cannot understand why it throws an exception but accepts a **String** as a ARN.

I have seen a webpage for troubleshooting this case with CloudTrail but cannot find it anymore.

Can someone shed some light into this or point me into the right direction? TIA

Comment: Are there any parameters actually passed to the stack or are the default values used?

Comment: No, those Parameters are not passed to the template (ProdEmailFromAddress and TestEmailFromAddress) the goal is to use the default values.

Comment: Hello all thanks, i was able to solve it, i will post the answer :)

Answer (score 5):

We were able to fix it by changing the **ARN** in the Parameters section, and using a **Join** as below:

```
Parameters:

  ProdEmailFromAddress:
    Type: String
    Description: "Email address to use as sender"
    Default: "no-reply@company.no"

  TestEmailFromAddress:
    Type: String
    Description: "Email address to use as sender"
    Default: "no-reply@companytest.no"

  ...

  SESAccessPolicy:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      Description: Permissions to send email from SES
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - Effect: "Allow"
            Action:
              - "ses:SendEmail"
            Resource:
              - !Join [ "", [ !Sub "arn:aws:ses:eu-west-1:${AWS::AccountId}:identity/", !If [ IsProductionDeployment, !Ref ProdEmailFromAddress,!Ref TestEmailFromAddress ] ] ]
```

Thanks